# Ruby - ideas for auto complete algorithm

Tags: ruby, algorithm

i'm currently working on a autocomplete algorithm for street names.
I get a file as parameters which are my adresses in this formats:

```
City,<SPACE>StreetNumber<SPACE>StreetName\n
```

City and StreetName can be completed on the full word (so if the city is "La Rochelle", the algorithm should display "La Rochelle" if read 'L' or 'R')

I get the user input from STDIN 1 characters at the time.

Here are some exemples if you didn't understand already :

```
    /B-ADM-442> ./autoCompletion exampleDict 2>\dev\null < test2
    l
    i
    v
    2

    /B-ADM-442> ./autoCompletion exampleDict 2>\dev\null < test2
    {m} {l} {p} {s} {d}
    {Li} {Ly}
    {LILLE, d} {LILLE, v} {LILLE, g} {LILLE, h} {LILLE, p}
    {1 :  LILLE, 30 rue VICTOR danel} {2 :  LILLE, 120 boulevard VICTOR hugo}
    => Lille, 120 boulevard Victor Hugo
```

Currently i'm able to complete only the City so "LILLE" but now i'm kinda stuck and i don't know how to do the rest of the complete.

if you have some questions don't hesitate to ask.

Here is my code so far, it's kinda big but i'm kinda ruby noob :)

```
    #!/usr/bin/env ruby
    #coding: utf-8

    require 'set'

    ##  ___________ _____ _____ 
    ## |_   _| ___ \_   _|  ___|
    ##    | | | |_/ / | | | |__  
    ##    | | |    /  | | |  __| 
    ##    | | | |\ \ _| |_| |___ 
    ##    \_/ \_| \_|\___/\____/ 
    ##

    class Trie

      attr_accessor :children, :value, :flag

      def initialize value=nil
        @children = {}
        @value = value
        @flag = false
      end

      def add char
        val = value ? value + char : char
        children[char] = Trie.new val
      end

      def insert word
        node = self
        word.each_char do |char|
          node.add char if not node.children.has_key? char
          node = node.children[char]
        end
        node.flag = true
      end

      def find word
        node = self
        word.each_char do |char|
          return nil if not node.children.has_key? char
          node = node.children[char]
        end
        return node.value
      end

      def all_prefixes
        results = Set.new
        results.add value if flag
        return results if children.empty?

        ap = children.values.collect {|node| node.all_prefixes}

        reduced = ap.reduce {|a,b| a.merge b}
        reduced or results
      end

      def autocomplete prefix
        node = self
        prefix.each_char do |char|
          return Set.new if not node.children.has_key? char
          node = node.children[char]
        end
        return node.all_prefixes
      end

    end

    ## ______ _____ _____ _____ _____ _____ _   _  _   _           ___          ________   __
    ## |  _  \_   _/  __ \_   _|_   _|  _  | \ | || \ | | / _ \ | ___ \         \ / /
    ## | | | | | | | /  \/ | |   | | | | | |  \| ||  \| |/ /_\ \| |_/ /\         V / 
    ## | | | | | | | |     | |   | | | | | | . ` || . ` ||  _  ||    /          \ /  
    ## | |/ / _| |_| \__/\ | |  _| |_\ \_/ / |\  || |\  || | | || |\ \          | |  
    ## |___/  \___/ \____/ \_/  \___/ \___/\_| \_/\_| \_/\_| |_/\_| \_|         \_/  
    ##

    class Dictionnary

      def initialize file, trieCity, trieStreet
        @validLine = /[a-zA-ZáàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ' ._-]+, \d+ [a-zA-Z0-9áàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ' ._-]+/
        @streetTypes = Array["allée", "avenue", "boulevard", "chemin", "impasse", "place", "quai", "rue", "square"]
        @regCity = /[a-zA-ZáàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ' ._-]+/
        @regStreetName = /[a-zA-ZáàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ' ._-]+, \d+ ([a-zA-Z0-9áàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ' ._-]+)/
        @regStreetNumber = /[a-zA-ZáàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ' ._-]+, (\d+) [a-zA-Z0-9áàâäãåçéèêëíìîïñóòôöõúùûüýÿæœÁÀÂÄÃÅÇÉÈÊËÍÌÎÏÑÓÒÔÖÕÚÙÛÜÝŸÆŒ' ._-]+/
        @trieCity = trieCity
        @trieStreet = trieStreet
        @trieLine = Trie.new
        @f_letter = Array.new
        @city = String.new
        @street = String.new
        @cityComplete = false
        begin
          @file = File.new(file.to_s, "r")
        rescue => err
          puts "Invalid argument"
          exit 84
        end
        counter = 0
        while line = @file.gets
          if @validLine.match(line)
            line[@regCity].split.each {|words|                         @f_letter.push(words.downcase)}
            line[@regCity].split.each {|words|         @trieCity.insert(words.downcase)}
            street = line.scan(@regStreetName).to_s.split[0].match(@regCity)
            @trieStreet.insert(line.scan(@regStreetName).last.first)
          end
          counter += 1
        end
        if counter == 0
          puts "Invalid argument"
          exit 84
        end
      end

      def prompt
        hash = @f_letter.each.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) {|word, hsh|         hsh[word[0].downcase] += 1}
        hash = Hash[hash.sort_by {|k, v| [-v, k] }]
        counter = 1
        hash.each do |k, _|
          print "{#{k}}"
          if counter < 5 && counter < hash.size
            print " "
          else
            print "\n"
            break
          end
          counter += 1
        end
      end

      def handle_input char
        if @cityComplete == false
          self.complete_city(char)
        else
          self.complete_street(char)
        end
      end

      def complete_city char
        @city.insert(@city.size, char)
        array = @trieCity.autocomplete(@city)
        if array.size == 1
          @city = array.first.dup
          @cityComplete = true
          return
        end
        counter = 1
        array.each do |word|
          print "{#{word.chars.first((@city.size) + 1).join.capitalize}}"
          if counter < 5 && counter < array.size
            print " "
          else
            print "\n"
            break
          end
          counter += 1
        end
      end

      def complete_street char
        puts @city
        puts char
        @street.insert(@street.size, char)
        array = @trieStreet.autocomplete(@street)
        puts array.inspect
      end
    end

    ##  ___________ _____ _____ _____ _   _  _____ 
    ## |  _  | ___ \_   _|_   _|  _  | \ | |/  ___|
    ## | | | | |_/ / | |   | | | | | |  \| |\ `--. 
    ## | | | |  __/  | |   | | | | | | . ` | `--. \
    ## \ \_/ / |     | |  _| |_\ \_/ / |\  |/\__/ /
    ##  \___/\_|     \_/  \___/ \___/\_| \_/\____/

    if !ARGV[0]
      puts "Invalid argument"
      exit 84
    end

    if ARGV[0] == "-h"
      puts "USAGE"
      puts "\t./autocompletion dictionnary\n\n"
      puts "DESCRIPTION"
      puts "\tdictionnary\tfile, containing one address per line,         serving as knowledge base"
      exit 0
    end

    ## ___  ___  ___  _____ _   _ 
    ## |  \/  | / _ \|_   _| \ | |
    ## | .  . |/ /_\ \ | | |  \| |
    ## | |\/| ||  _  | | | | . ` |
    ## | |  | || | | |_| |_| |\  |
    ## \_|  |_/\_| |_/\___/\_| \_/


    trie1 = Trie.new
    trie2 = Trie.new
    dictionnary = Dictionnary.new(ARGV[0], trie1, trie2)
    dictionnary.prompt
    while user_input = STDIN.gets
      user_input ||= ''
      user_input.chomp!
      case user_input
      when "ABORT"
        exit 0
      else
        if user_input.size > 1
          exit 84
        end
        dictionnary.handle_input(user_input[0])
      end
    end
```

Thanks,
Thomas

Comment: You forgot to post the code you've written so far.

Comment: @Jordan Updated with code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started, have a look at readlines, combined with abbrev (both from standard lib).

```
require "abbrev"
require "readline"  
arr = ["Marseille", "Marsan", "Martin"]

Readline.completion_proc = arr.abbrev.to_proc

while buffer = Readline.readline(">", true) # true means: keep history.
  exit if buffer.strip == "quit"
  p buffer
end
```

- Autocompletion by pressing tab, so "Mart(tab)" results in Martin
- History is accessible by up- and down key
- hash.to_proc is relatively new, may not be available.